# Configuration problem with asp.net ajax control toolkit 3.5

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the control toolkit installed properly (dll in the application's bin folder, able to add controls to toolbox in VS)

My problem is that none of the controls work for me, I'm almost certain that I'm missing something in my setup.

For example:

**Accordion Pane:** Headers are rendered but the panes aren't clickable (and thus don't expand)

**ComboBox:** The control is rendered but list items are not displayed (I've tried with static list items and databound items)

See code below.

```
Other Info

Windows Server 2008 64 bit
VS 2008
.NET 3.5
```

**ACCORDION**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Using the AJAX Control Toolkit in ASP.NET 3.5</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

Password: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" /><br />
<cc1:PasswordStrength ID="TextBox1_PasswordStrength" runat="server"
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
</cc1:PasswordStrength>
<cc1:DropShadowExtender ID="TextBox1_DropShadowExtender" runat="server"
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
</cc1:DropShadowExtender>
<br />
<br />
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" RequireOpenedPane="false">
<Panes>
<cc1:AccordionPane ID="AccPane1" runat="server">
<Header>This is Pane 1.</Header>
<Content><br />This is pane one content.</Content>
</cc1:AccordionPane>
<cc1:AccordionPane ID="AccPane2" runat="server">
<Header>This is Pane 2.</Header>
<Content><br />This is pane two content.</Content>
</cc1:AccordionPane>
<cc1:AccordionPane ID="AccPane3" runat="server">
<Header>This is Pane 3.</Header>
<Content><br />This is pane three content.</Content>
</cc1:AccordionPane>
</Panes>
</cc1:Accordion>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**ComboBox**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSelection.Text = "You picked " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text;        
    }
</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Static</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

        Describe how spicy you like your food:
        <br />
        <cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" RenderMode="Block">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Mi65y6yld" Value="0" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Hot" Value="2" />
        </cc1:ComboBox>

        <asp:Button
            ID="btnSubmit"
            Text="Submit"
            Runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />

        <hr />
        <asp:Label
            ID="lblSelection"
            Runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

I had to add these script references to my script manager:

```
<Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" Path="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/MicrosoftAjax.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference ScriptMode="Inherit" Path="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference ScriptMode="Inherit" Path="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/MicrosoftAjaxAdoNet.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference ScriptMode="Inherit" Path="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.js" />
            </Scripts>
```